# GWT-RPC serialization fails to generate proper payload

Tags: java, gwt

I'm facing an issue with GWT-RPC which I'm currently struggling to find a solution to. I have this RPC call:

```
public abstract class MyAppOverviewController extends MyAppBaseController {

    protected void onDelete(final AppEvent event) {
        ClientSession.showDeleting();
        
        commonWebClientServiceAsync.delete(getCommonRequestModel(event, getRequiredDefaultValues()), new AsyncCallback<CommonResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CommonResponseModel result) {
                forwardToView(view, new AppEvent(event.getType(), result));
                event.setData(null);
                        
                if (getReloadEvent() != null) {
                    Dispatcher.forwardEvent(getReloadEvent());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Dispatcher.forwardEvent(CommonEvents.Error, caught);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I end up in the onFailure() method and I can see in the browser network tab, that the payload is missing entirely:

[image]

The error message int he caught Throwable is not very telling to me:

```
Error: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 0  
    at UPn_g$.A5b_g$ [as createError_0_g$] (myappWebGui-0.js:44938:10)
    at UPn_g$.L5b_g$ [as initializeBackingError_0_g$] (myappWebGui-0.js:45001:44)
    at UPn_g$.u5b_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:44854:8)
    at UPn_g$.a6b_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:45119:10)
    at UPn_g$.e6k_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:287308:10)
    at UPn_g$.WNn_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:316166:10)
    at new UPn_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:316719:10)
    at _ao_g$.cbo_g$ [as onResponseReceived_0_g$] (myappWebGui-0.js:323154:21)
    at NSm_g$.QSm_g$ [as fireOnResponseReceived_0_g$] (myappWebGui-0.js:300875:17)
    at CTm_g$.DTm_g$ [as onReadyStateChange_0_g$] (myappWebGui-0.js:301183:28)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (myappWebGui-0.js:332669:18)
    at Lel_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:288705:28)
    at Oel_g$ (myappWebGui-0.js:288761:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (myappWebGui-0.js:288741:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.qe (http://localhost:8080/eWorld/logstar.js:2:11440)
    at T.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/eWorld/logstar.js:2:7159)
    at I.runTask (http://localhost:8080/eWorld/logstar.js:2:2554)
    at m.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8080/eWorld/logstar.js:2:8210)
    at S (http://localhost:8080/eWorld/logstar.js:2:20109)
    at XMLHttpRequest.D (http://localhost:8080/eWorld/logstar.js:2:20353)
```

I'm not very proficient when it come to GWT-RPC debugging. how can I find out what goes wrong here during serialization?